# Android Synchronizing Listeners for return value for ONVIF devices

Tags: java, android, synchronization, onvif

I have several listeners that are returning values from a ONVIF device search.

I have code that finds the ONVIF devices (IP addresses) and then does a for loop for each device to iterate through the device list.  For every device I am creating a listener for the device to retrieve the media URL stream.  (so if there are two ONVIF cameras, I need to see what each camera's stream URL is)

Due to multi threading, I am often receiving the return values from these listeners at the same time (in this case the media URL information)

I need to be able to update a single ArrayList with these values, and know when all the devices have returned the values from the listeners I instantiated.

I am confused if there is a way to use a synchronized type for this?

I have looked up several tutorials about making a listener "thread safe" but I cannot find anyone creating several identical listeners to track the results from.

Here be the code.  The "appendResultsText" the function being called once the listener is triggered.  The uri String is the value that I am needing to append to the array (which I do but not reliably)

```
onvifManager.getMediaProfiles(device1, new OnvifMediaProfilesListener() {
      @Override
      public void onMediaProfilesReceived(@Nonnullbe.teletask.onvif.models.OnvifDevice device,
                                                            @Nonnull List<OnvifMediaProfile> mediaProfiles) {

      onvifManager.getMediaStreams(device, mediaProfiles.get(0), new OnvifMediaStreamURIListener() {
           @Override
           public void onMediaStreamURIReceived(@Nonnull be.teletask.onvif.models.OnvifDevice device,
                                                                     @Nonnull OnvifMediaProfile profile, @Nonnull String uri) {

                appendResultsText(uri, nThisDeviceTrack, nDeviceTotal, lShowNotifications_x, lVxgViewRefresh_x );


           }
      });
    }
 });
```

Shoutout to RootSoft at https://github.com/RootSoft/ONVIF-Java for the awesome ONVIF discovery library!

As a side note this is running as an IntentService so it is outside the UI threads.

Comment: If possible why you don't use a Vector instaed an ArrayList ? https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Vector
Vector are Thread Safe and you don't need more efforts to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to be able to update a single ArrayList with these values

Since mutations might be more then traversals, use a `synchronized List<T>`.

```
final List<T> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<T>());
```

Alternatively, if your list cannot be synchronized, you might want to use a temporary `ArrayBlockingQueue<T>` to queue your results, and then `drainTo` your `ArrayList<T>` once all the devices have returned their values.

Comment: when using Collections.synchronizedList the user need to synchronize manually if they want iterate it. Look https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List%3CT%3E)